# Configure hbase in pseudo distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to configure hbase in pseudo distributed mode. I have tried many tutorials but every time i get this error in my log

```
2014-04-29 16:47:47,029 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Failed assignment of -ROOT-,,0.70236052 to serverName=localhost,60020,1398804454531, load=(requests=0, regions=0, usedHeap=0, maxHeap=0), trying to assign elsewhere instead; retry=0
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed setting up proxy interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HRegionInterface to /127.0.0.1:60020 after attempts=1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.waitForProxy(HBaseRPC.java:355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHRegionConnection(HConnectionManager.java:969)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager.getServerConnection(ServerManager.java:620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager.sendRegionOpen(ServerManager.java:555)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1043)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:858)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:838)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assignRoot(AssignmentManager.java:1304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.assignRootAndMeta(HMaster.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:282)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:883)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:750)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC$Invoker.invoke(HBaseRPC.java:257)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.waitForProxy(HBaseRPC.java:349)
    ... 10 more
2014-04-29 16:47:47,052 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Unable to find a viable location to assign region -ROOT-,,0.70236052
```

I have tried following solutions

- remove 127.0.1.1 from /etc/hosts file
- forcing for IPV4 in hbase-env.sh

My hbase-site.xml is this

```
<configuration>
      <property>
           <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
            <value>file:///home/freeswitch/TryNutch/hbase</value>
       </property>
       <property>
          <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
          <value>true</value>
       </property>
      <property>
           <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
           <value>/home/freeswitch/TryNutch/zookeeper</value>
       </property>
</configuration>
```

Thank for reading this post.
your help is much needed.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, replace `file:///home/freeswitch/TryNutch/hbase` with proper value if you intend to run HBase in distributed mode. I can see `hbase.cluster.distributed` set to true. Point it to your NameNode address. Something like `hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase`.

Also, add the following two properties in your hbase-site.xml file :

```
<property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>localhost</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
</property>
```

Make sure your NameNode is running fine, and restart HBase daemons. If you still face any problem try following this **[link](http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-configure-habse-in-pseudo.html#.U1_9Z62SwrQ)**. I have tried to explain the procedure in detail. Let me know if you still face any issue.

HTH